# no funciona javascript transition solo si es con el debug

Tags: javascript, html, transicion

Buenas estoy intentando crear una transicion por javascript la cual al momento de usar el debug de cualquier browser me funciona pero si no se usa el debug no funciona alguna ayuda?

```js
var pos = 0;
function prev() {
    nex = document.getElementsByClassName('imghid');
    nex[pos].style.display = "none";
    nex[pos].style.opacity = "0";
    pos += -1;
    if (pos < 0) {
        pos = 2;
    }
    nex[pos].style.display = "block";
    nex[pos].style.transition = "all 5s";
    nex[pos].style.opacity = "1";
    
}
```

```html
 <div class="imgprin">
<input value=">" type="button" id="next" class="btnim" onclick="prev(1)"/>
<div class="immgs" id="img1">
<img src="img/party.jpg" class="imghid" id="imgst"  />
<img src="img/party2.jpg" class="imghid" id="imgst2" />
<img src="img/party3.jpg" class="imghid" id="imgst3" />
</div>
```

Comment: Primero reemplazá el `value=">"` por `value="&gt;"` porque eso está rompiendo el HTML. Segundo, el transition nunca se va a ver porque el estás aplicando al mismo tiempo un display none. Explicá que es lo que querés hacer así evaluamos mejor una posible solución.

Comment: Dale perfecto ahora lo pruebo lo del html no sabia que se rompia con >,  luego lo de java lo pjde resolver sacando el display, es para pasar imagenes para que haga efecto tipo fade. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El display none tapa el efecto. Si lo comentas ves que hace el efecto de transición, he añadido un fondo de color para que sea más evidente en el ejemplo.

```js
var pos = 0;
function prev() {
    nex = document.getElementsByClassName('imghid');
    /*nex[pos].style.display = "none";*/
    nex[pos].style.opacity = "0";
    pos += -1;
    if (pos < 0) {
        pos = 2;
    }
    nex[pos].style.display = "block";
    nex[pos].style.background = "red";
    nex[pos].style.WebkitTransition = "all 5s";
    nex[pos].style.transition = "all 5s";
    nex[pos].style.opacity = "1";
    
}
```

```html
 <div class="imgprin">
<input value=">" type="button" id="next" class="btnim" onclick="prev(1)"/>
<div class="immgs" id="img1">
<span class="imghid" id="imgst1">element 1</span>
<span class="imghid" id="imgst2">element 2</span>
<span class="imghid" id="imgst3">element 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Si lo pude resolver sacando el display y poniendole un width=0 y luego con java lo modifico y uso el trransition opacity. :D